# How do I make a selection based on a previous selection?

Tags: javascript

For a learning excercise, I'm building a car builder page and want to select car color, then wheel style, with the picture of the car changing to reflect each unique color/wheel combination. There are 16 colors and 5 wheel styles, and I have a picture that represents each unique value.

I was able to work out the first steps to select the car color and the wheel option separately of each other. For example if I click the red car color, I want the color to stay while I cycle through the wheel options. Currently, it defaults back to black, then cycles through the wheels for the black color only.

I'm failing to understand the general logic that should be used to approach a simple two-option combination like this, and things I try like capturing the selected option with a variable to carry it over to the wheel selection breaks the functionality. Can anyone point me in the proper general direction?

Here is the page in its current state - https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche/index.html

I know why the code isn't working - but I don't know how to start laying out to factor the two selections together.

Any guidance would be greatly appreaciated!

```
Button code:
<ul id="example4" class="accordion">
<li class="active">
<h3 class="accord">Exterior Colors</h3>
<div class="panel loading">
<h5 class="option-subhead">Standard Colors</h5>  
<input id="exterior-swatch1" type="button" value=" " onclick="color1()" class="swatch" /> 
<input id="exterior-swatch2" type="button" value=" " onclick="color2()" class="swatch" />   
<input id="exterior-swatch3" type="button" value=" " onclick="color3()" class="swatch" />    
<input id="exterior-swatch4" type="button" value=" " onclick="color4()" class="swatch" />   
<h5 class="option-subhead">Metallic Colors</h5>
<input id="exterior-swatch5" type="button" value=" " onclick="color5()" class="swatch" />    
<input id="exterior-swatch6" type="button" value=" " onclick="color6()" class="swatch" />   
<input id="exterior-swatch7" type="button" value=" " onclick="color7()" class="swatch" />    
<input id="exterior-swatch8" type="button" value=" " onclick="color8()" class="swatch" /><br>
<input id="exterior-swatch9" type="button" value=" " onclick="color9()" class="swatch" />    
<input id="exterior-swatch10" type="button" value=" " onclick="color10()" class="swatch" />   
<input id="exterior-swatch11" type="button" value=" " onclick="color11()" class="swatch" />    
<input id="exterior-swatch12" type="button" value=" " onclick="color12()" class="swatch" />  
<h5 class="option-subhead">Special Colors</h5>
<input id="exterior-swatch13" type="button" value=" " onclick="color13()" class="swatch" />    
<input id="exterior-swatch14" type="button" value=" " onclick="color14()" class="swatch" />   
<input id="exterior-swatch15" type="button" value=" " onclick="color15()" class="swatch" />    
<input id="exterior-swatch16" type="button" value=" " onclick="color16()" class="swatch" />
</div>
</li>

<li>
<h3 class="accord">Wheel Options</h3>   
<div class="panel loading">
<img src="images/carerra-s/wheels/wheel1.png" alt="Wheel Option 1" id="wheel1" class="wheels" onclick="wheeloption1()" />
<img src="images/carerra-s/wheels/wheel2.png" alt="Wheel Option 2" id="wheel2" class="wheels" onclick="wheeloption2()" />
<img src="images/carerra-s/wheels/wheel3.png" alt="Wheel Option 3" id="wheel3" class="wheels" onclick="wheeloption3()" />
<img src="images/carerra-s/wheels/wheel4.png" alt="Wheel Option 4" id="wheel4" class="wheels" onclick="wheeloption4()" />
<img src="images/carerra-s/wheels/wheel5.png" alt="Wheel Option 5" id="wheel5" class="wheels" onclick="wheeloption5()" />
</div>
</li>
</ul>



3 Examples of a total of 16 for all the colors...

<script>
function color1() {
document.getElementById("carerra").src = 'images/carerra-s/exterior/View3-Color1.png';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch1").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color1-checked.png");';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch2").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color2.png");';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch3").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color3.png");';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch4").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color4.png");';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch5").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color5.png");';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch6").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color6.png");';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch7").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color7.png");';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch8").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color8.png");';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch9").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color9.png");';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch10").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color10.png");';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch11").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color11.png");';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch12").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color12.png");';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch13").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color13.png");';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch14").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color14.png");';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch15").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color15.png");';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch16").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color16.png");';
var colorPath = 'images/carerra-s/wheels/color1';
}

<!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - CAR COLOR 2 - WHITE - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
function color2() {
document.getElementById("carerra").src = 'images/carerra-s/exterior/View3-Color2.png';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch2").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color2-checked.png");';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch1").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color1.png");';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch3").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color3.png");';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch4").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color4.png");';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch5").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color5.png");';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch6").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color6.png");';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch7").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color7.png");';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch8").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color8.png");';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch9").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color9.png");';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch10").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color10.png");';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch11").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color11.png");';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch12").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color12.png");';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch13").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color13.png");';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch14").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color14.png");';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch15").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color15.png");';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch16").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color16.png");';  
var colorPath = "images/carerra-s/wheels/color2";
}
<!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - CAR COLOR 3 - YELLOW - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
function color3() {
document.getElementById("carerra").src = 'images/carerra-s/exterior/View3-Color3.png';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch3").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color3-checked.png");';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch1").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color1.png");';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch2").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color2.png");';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch4").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color4.png");';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch5").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color5.png");';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch6").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color6.png");';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch7").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color7.png");';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch8").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color8.png");';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch9").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color9.png");';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch10").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color10.png");';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch11").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color11.png");';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch12").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color12.png");';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch13").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color13.png");';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch14").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color14.png");';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch15").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color15.png");';
document.getElementById("exterior-swatch16").style = 'background-image: url("images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color16.png");';
var colorPath = "images/carerra-s/wheels/color3";
}

  <!-- - - - - - - -  WHEEL SCRIPTS STUFF - - - - - - -->

function wheeloption1()
```

{document.getElementById("carerra").src = 'images/carerra-s/wheels/color1-option1.png';
document.getElementById("wheel1").src = 'images/carerra-s/wheels/wheel1-checked.png';
document.getElementById("wheel2").src = 'images/carerra-s/wheels/wheel2.png';
document.getElementById("wheel3").src = 'images/carerra-s/wheels/wheel3.png';
document.getElementById("wheel4").src = 'images/carerra-s/wheels/wheel4.png';
document.getElementById("wheel5").src = 'images/carerra-s/wheels/wheel5.png';}

```
function wheeloption2()
```

{document.getElementById("carerra").src = 'images/carerra-s/wheels/color1-option2.png';
document.getElementById("wheel2").src = 'images/carerra-s/wheels/wheel2-checked.png';
document.getElementById("wheel1").src = 'images/carerra-s/wheels/wheel1.png';
document.getElementById("wheel3").src = 'images/carerra-s/wheels/wheel3.png';
document.getElementById("wheel4").src = 'images/carerra-s/wheels/wheel4.png';
document.getElementById("wheel5").src = 'images/carerra-s/wheels/wheel5.png';}

```
function wheeloption3()
```

{document.getElementById("carerra").src = 'images/carerra-s/wheels/color1-option3.png';
document.getElementById("wheel3").src = 'images/carerra-s/wheels/wheel3-checked.png';
document.getElementById("wheel1").src = 'images/carerra-s/wheels/wheel1.png';
document.getElementById("wheel2").src = 'images/carerra-s/wheels/wheel2.png';
document.getElementById("wheel4").src = 'images/carerra-s/wheels/wheel4.png';
document.getElementById("wheel5").src = 'images/carerra-s/wheels/wheel5.png';}

```
function wheeloption4()
```

{document.getElementById("carerra").src = 'images/carerra-s/wheels/color1-option4.png';
document.getElementById("wheel4").src = 'images/carerra-s/wheels/wheel4-checked.png';
document.getElementById("wheel1").src = 'images/carerra-s/wheels/wheel1.png';
document.getElementById("wheel2").src = 'images/carerra-s/wheels/wheel2.png';
document.getElementById("wheel3").src = 'images/carerra-s/wheels/wheel3.png';
document.getElementById("wheel5").src = 'images/carerra-s/wheels/wheel5.png';}

```
function wheeloption5()
```

{document.getElementById("carerra").src = 'images/carerra-s/wheels/color1-option5.png';
document.getElementById("wheel5").src = 'images/carerra-s/wheels/wheel5-checked.png';
document.getElementById("wheel1").src = 'images/carerra-s/wheels/wheel1.png';
document.getElementById("wheel2").src = 'images/carerra-s/wheels/wheel2.png';
document.getElementById("wheel3").src = 'images/carerra-s/wheels/wheel3.png';
document.getElementById("wheel4").src = 'images/carerra-s/wheels/wheel4.png';}

Comment: I'm afraid just a link to your website doesn't provide much information in the question.  This is your opportunity to start doing some debugging to narrow down the problem.  Focus specifically on exactly what your code does when you set a wheel option.  Make use of your browser's debugging tools to step through the code in the script debugger, observe useful runtime values, etc.  You should be able to isolate the specific operation which isn't doing what you want.  If the result of that operation is unclear to you, provide the relevant code and inputs in the question.

Comment: The issue is simple. Whenever you are clicking on the wheel, you are loading black car with that selected wheel. This overrides the selected car color. Either you need to create all color + all wheel type car images and bring it based on the selection. If you already has those images then on the click function of wheel check the color selected and load appropriate image

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys - I understand why my code/logic isn't working - i just don't know how to structure my code so it factors both elements with each other - the logic approach of it.

I understand the basic if/then logic, but not quite sure how to implement it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say without seeing your code, but it seems like you are changing *everything* in one function rather than setting the value of each individual item separately.

For example, it seems like you are using a `setStyle()` function to set color, wheels, interior, etc. all in one function. What you may want to do is have separate functions `setColor()`, `setWheels()`, etc which only do one thing and don't touch the other styles.

EDIT:
Here is the issue. In your wheel selection functions, you are changing the entire image of the carerra:

```
function wheelOption1() {
    document.getElementById("carerra").src = 'images/carerra-s/wheels/color1-option1.png';
.... }
```

Look in your `images/carerra-s/wheels` folder, at `color1-option1.png`. You are setting the source of your `#carerra` element to be that picture. There's nothing magic with old options getting reset, your logic is explicitly telling your page, "When this function runs, change the image that is displayed to be `color1-option1.png`, which is an image of a black car."

Unfortunately 'solving the issue' is a lot more complex than answering the question of why does this happen. I would recommend you break your car image into multiple component parts, with a separate image for the car body, the wheels, and the interior. So for example, your car body images would simply have the wheels and interior edited out, and your wheels and interior would ONLY show the wheels and interior. From there you could have a `<div>` for your car, and four separate images in that div that contain the images for the body, the front wheel, the rear wheel, and the interior. From there, [relatively position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) all the separate images so they are overlaying each other correctly. And then your functions can solely change the source image for the images you want to change, and nothing else will need to be reset.

Comment: When I post my code, it's way too long and I exceed the character limit for the comment field?

Comment: Okay, I was able to post some of the code I'm using. I know why my code doesn't do what I want it to, but can't seem to understand how to start coding to factor both selections.

Would I do and if/then for all combos? A switch statement? An array?

Comment: I see a couple things. Char limit in comments so I'll be brief - 1) Doesn't make sense to reset your color swatches in each color function. All you want to happen is to update the color on the actual car, so just do that; 2) You could refactor to just have 1 function that changes color, pass it an argument, and have your function choose the color from there. Would make things massively DRYer - all your code for color selections would be less than 10 lines; 3) You didn't add any of your wheel selector code so I can't see why selecting a wheel would reset the color.

Comment: Thank you rook218, I appreciate your time. I've added the wheel selection script. I feel like I'm missing the boat when it comes to logic on this. I know experienced JavaScript guys could accomplish this with little code, but I'm self taught, and am finding many holes in my knowledge base!

Comment: No worries, I am self-taught as well and just a few years ahead of you. I very much remember having questions just like this :). We have all been here. I've updated my answer for you.

Comment: Okay, thanks again for your effort. People like you are invaluable for people like me :o)

I'll take a fresh approach and see if I can make it happen. I really do appreaciate you guys. Have a great week!

Comment: No worries, hope you can plug through it. Comment here if you need any more help, when I'm not on the clock I could get a little demo going in a JS fiddle or something. And help out the community by voting on posts that are helpful and marking the best answers to your questions

Comment: You're too kind - I started to make a fiddle yesterday, but separating the code in question from the page was taking too long, and I had other things I had to do so I had to bail on it. I'm also realizing I'm not framing the question well, but you seem to understand what I'm trying to do. I'm going to get some other things done, but will be back on this shortly - I really want to slay this dragon! Thanks again for all your excellent help - you rock, sir! How can I upvote your comments? I'd love to give back any way I can. I think I just cast an upvote for you...;o)

Comment: No worries, I remember what it was like getting stuck as a beginner, and how having someone to just bounce ideas off of would have helped enormously. You're asking interesting questions and taking on a big project. I'm glad to help. You're too new to upvote anything (you have to have a certain reputation to do that) but if you click the green checkmark under the voting buttons you can mark mine as the answer if you'd like.

Comment: I have so much to learn, and you guys are invaluable! I'll click the checkmark - always happy to give credit to folks.